# Speed up transaction processing in a private chain

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions

Given a private chain where all transactions are sent with the same amount of gas and gasprice, is it possible to speed up transaction processing by lowering the complexity of a block?

Or by any other way :)

Comment: `geth --dev` offers a developer optimised chain.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to run as dev. It is 'production'.

Comment: Had you solved this issue? Genesis file has option difficulty which you can set to zero.